# What is the best approach to handle Refund for payment done thru the Square Register API

Tags: square-connect

I am experimenting with the Android Register API, and I am trying to find a way to handle refund. Assuming a normal transaction of my setup is like the following:

1. Using my app, I scanned items into an open order
2. Click a button in my app, and it passes all the necessary info to the Square app thru the Register API
3. The Square app process the payment, pass data back to my app
4. My app records the data passed back by the Square app, and save the transaction

All sounds great UNTIL I need to do a refund. Nothing the Register API saved and passed back can be used to find out a receipt **USING** the Square app. As far as I can tell, the only way I can easily trace a transaction back is to record the transaction ID passed back by the Register API, then implement a refund feature in my app using the Connect API.

Can the Register API just pass the recipt ID? This way, one can easily look up a recipt using the Square app and issue a refund from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process a refund through the Register app, you will need to perform a [Retrieve Transaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-retrievetransaction) call with the Connect API using the transaction ID that the Register app should pass back to your app. In that response you will get info like the last four of the card used in the transaction that you can use to lookup the transaction in the app.